# Is it possible to have a current higher than the transformer short circuit one?

Tags: current, transformer, protection, short-circuit, power-grid

I am a student and I want to understand the following aspect.

I know that protections and whatever devices installed in the grid must tolerate a current higher than the short circuit current. At the low voltage level, I want to know the short circuit current in order to understand which devices I have to buy, depending on the maximum current they can tolerate.

I know it is equal to the short circuit current of the secondary transformer, but is it possibile to have a current higher than that? What happens if a current higher than the short circuit current of the transformer flows through it?

Comment: How would that happen?

Comment: Short circuit contribution from the primary side of the transformer?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to protect and, specifically from what?

Comment: @Andyaka I have to protect inverters, panels, and human lives. Protections have to tollerate the maximum short circuit current in the circuit

Comment: "*I have to protect inverters, panels, and human lives*" If that's your responsibility, then that's quite a thing to be trusting to answers on some internet Q&A site.

Comment: @TonyM I am studying, I am not working of course... I am a student and I want to learn. That was a curiosity it came into my mind and that could be useful in the future in order to design PV plant.

Comment: Then please edit your question to add that introduction text to your question.

Comment: So is this homework? If so, you need to show that you have attempted to find a solution by yourself.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy it is not homework... No calculations needed... It is just understanding the physical phenomenon described above...

Comment: If you're talking about human lives, you usually need to take component failure into account -- so usually the answer to your question is "yes"

Comment: @SamueleBenitoDiGioia you are asking about current limiting devices in a grid system and, are linking their use to the prevention of human harm. Could you please explain how risk to human life is reduced with this type of protection?

Comment: @Andyaka I am not asking about current limiting devices. Every device must tollerate the maximum short circuit current in the point of installation, otherwise they will not work and would be destroyed in case of such currents. I know how to calculate this reference value, I just want to know about the phenomenon described above, if that case may happen or not

Comment: @ScottSeidman sorry man, I didn't understand your answer with my question. The question is: is it possible to have a current higher than the short circuit current of the secondary side of the MV/LV  transformer at a low voltage side?

Comment: Please show with a schematic and calculation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have a current higher than the transformer short circuit one?

Yes it is possible.

Let \$I_p\$ be the current through the primary in a given scenario, and \$I_{p0}\$ be the current through the primary with the secondary short circuited. Let \$I_s\$ be the current through the secondary in a given scenario, and \$I_{s0}\$ be the current through the secondary with the *secondary* shorted.

It is possible for \$I_p\$ to be greater than \$I_{p0}\$ if the transformer core is saturated. This can happen following the making of a connection between the power source and the transformer. If the connection is made when the instantaneous voltage is 0, and when the core is unmagnetized, the first half cycle can cause the core to go into saturation. Similarly, if the core has residual magnetization, there are some sections of the electrical cycle during which if a connection is made, the core will go into saturation.

The core can also go into saturation during lightning strikes.

Perhaps surprisingly, it is possible that \$I_s\$ might be greater than \$I_{s0}\$.

Basically, this could happen if there is a power source on the secondary side, and again the core needs to be saturated. Again, a lightning strike on the secondary side might do the trick. But there is also a rather obscure possibility. A motor on the secondary side could become a generator if instead of applying a power to its load, the load applies power to the motor/generator. Imagine a motor lifting some heavy weight, but due to loss of control, the weight starts falling. If the motor/generator spins fast enough, it could supply a voltage high enough to saturate the transformer, and the current could exceed that which would occur if the transformer secondary were shorted. Admittedly this might not be as common an occurrence as a lightning strike or the making of an electrical connection. However, it is a theoretical possibility.